# Words pronunciation in Windows Store Application (Windows 8 Metro)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm looking for a way for my Windows Store Application (Windows 8 Metro) to pronounce words. Microsoft Speech isn't available in WinRT. My programming language is C# and I'm working in a multi-language dictionary. I want to know is there any way for providing words pronunciation in my application? Even English words are enough for me.

Is there any way to use Google Translate Pronunciation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Translator service, that provides text-to-speech functionalities to applications. If you are interested in this solution, you can take a look to http://translatorservice.codeplex.com.